# How to start working on Adobe Processing rule?

Tags: adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

Actually there is one data my customer want to check -

Please create a processing rule to capture the default countries found in (visitor profile > geo-segmentation > countries report and populate in a new prop and evar. The new prop / evar will be different from the existing evar3 (countries) which captures the country selector from the footer. This new prop/evar will actually capture the country of origin based on Adobe's method of determining the country. The new variable should be named "geo-segmentation countries".

So i am very new in this, how to do it..if anybody can help me on this would be greatfull.

Thanks,
PD

Comment: the geo-segmentation dimensions are not exposed to processing rules.

Comment: You can not track it using processing rules, however you can check if VISTA rules can help.

Comment: Thankyou ketav and crayon